# Changing database from controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is it possible to select between the database from the controller?. I want a dropdown list in my view to change the database.

Comment: yes. it is possible.... you can use the selected database name in the connection string... what's the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

The connection to Db from a controller is equal to the connection from any other place.

You can use EF for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Or ADO.NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/step-3-connect-sql-ado-net?view=sql-server-ver15

```
using System;
using QC = Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
  
namespace ProofOfConcept_SQL_CSharp  
{  
    public class Program  
    {  
        static public void Main()  
        {  
            using (var connection = new QC.SqlConnection(  
                "Server=tcp:YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE.database.windows.net,1433;" +
                "Database=AdventureWorksLT;User ID=YOUR_LOGIN_NAME_HERE;" +
                "Password=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE;Encrypt=True;" +
                "TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"  
                ))  
            {  
                connection.Open();  
                Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully.");  

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish...");  
                Console.ReadKey(true);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```